# What does the Naturality law for Traversables mean?

Tags: haskell, types, applicative, traversable

The Naturality law states that:

```
t . traverse f == traverse (t . f) -- for every applicative transformer t
```

Now for the RHS of the law, if f has the type `Applicative a => x -> a y`, then t has to be of the type `(Applicative a, Applicative b) => a y -> b y`, due to the function composition.

For the LHS, traverse f has the type `(Applicative a, Traversable c) => c x -> a (c y)`. But since traverse f is composed with t . traverse f, t has to be of the type (c x -> a (c y)) -> b y.

Now, for the LHS, t has the type a (c y) -> b y, but from the RHS it has the type a y -> b y. How is the law sound from a type perspective?

Edit: Fixed the type t in LHS

Comment: Fixed the type of t in th LHS deduction. Still not sure how the law follows.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you have missed is that `t` is supposed to be a natural transformation (which also probably must have some structure-preserving properties).  Natural transformations are quantified, like so:

```
t :: forall z. a z -> b z   -- "t is an N.T. from a ~> b"
```

On the right we instantiate it at `y`, to get `t :: a y -> b y`; on the left we instantiate it at `c y` to get `a (c y) -> b (c y)`. The way I think of it is that a natural transformation changes the outer layer, no matter what is inside.  Naturality laws always talk about relationships between the different ways something is instantiated.

```
t                :: forall z. a z -> b z

f                :: x -> a y
t                :: a y -> b y           -- instantiated at y
t . f            :: x -> b y
traverse (t . f) :: c x -> b (c y)

traverse f       :: c x -> a (c y)
t                :: a (c y) -> b (c y)   -- instantiated at (c y)
t . traverse f   :: c x -> b (c y)
```